# Unknown Error in my code

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#define Pi 3.14159265358979323846
#define MAX_DATA 20


double Find_GrowthRate(double Data_6hr[MAX_DATA],double Data_24hr[MAX_DATA]);
double Find_DoublingTime(double GrowthRate[MAX_DATA]);


int main()
{
   int i;
   double t1;
   double Data_6hr[MAX_DATA] = {2.3,3.3,4.3,5.3,6.3,7.3,8.3,9.3,10.3,11.3,12.3,13.3,14.3,15.3,16.3,17.3,18.3,19.3,20.3,21.3};
   double Data_24hr[MAX_DATA] = {4.2,5.2,6.2,7.2,8.2,9.2,10.2,11.2,12.2,13.2,14.2,15.2,16.2,17.2,18.2,19.2,20.2,21.2,22.2,23.2};
   Find_GrowthRate(Data_6hr,Data_24hr);
   double *GrowthRate;
   printf("Growth Rates\n");
   for(i=0;i<MAX_DATA;i++){
      printf("%lf \n",*(GrowthRate+i));
   }
   Find_DoublingTime(GrowthRate);
   printf("Average Doubling Time");
   printf("%lf", t1);
   return 0;
}

double Find_GrowthRate(double Data_6hr[MAX_DATA], double Data_24hr[MAX_DATA])
{
   int i;

   double *GrowthRate;
   GrowthRate = (double*)malloc(MAX_DATA*sizeof(double));
   for(i=0;i<MAX_DATA;i++){
      double PopulationSize_t1 = (Pi * pow((Data_6hr[i]/ 2),2));
      printf("%lf\n",PopulationSize_t1);
      double PopulationSize_t2 = (Pi * pow((Data_24hr[i]/ 2),2));
      printf("%lf\n",PopulationSize_t2);
      double x = ((PopulationSize_t2 - PopulationSize_t1) / PopulationSize_t1);
      *(GrowthRate+i) = x;
   }
   printf("Growth Rates\n");
   for(i=0;i<MAX_DATA;i++){
      printf("%lf \n",*(GrowthRate+i));
   }

   return GrowthRate;

}
```

The error I receive is:-

error: incompatible types when returning type 'double *' but 'double was expected

Was wondering what the change is in my code I need to make, and whether i could make my code any better.

Comment: The return type of the function is `double` and the `return` statements returns `GrowthRage`, which is of type `double*`. That's the error.

Comment: `double Find_GrowthRate(..)` --> `double *Find_GrowthRate(..)`

Answer (score 1):

The function `Find_GrowthRate` is declared as having the return type `double`

```
double Find_GrowthRate(double Data_6hr[MAX_DATA],double Data_24hr[MAX_DATA]);
^^^^^^
```

However in the function definition the function returns an object of type `double *`

```
double Find_GrowthRate(double Data_6hr[MAX_DATA], double Data_24hr[MAX_DATA])
{
   int i;

   double *GrowthRate;
   //...
   return GrowthRate;
          ^^^^^^^^^^

}
```

Moreover there are memory leak because the dynamically allocated a memory pointed to by the pointer `GrowthRate` is not freed.

And in this loop

```
   double *GrowthRate;
   printf("Growth Rates\n");
   for(i=0;i<MAX_DATA;i++){
      printf("%lf \n",*(GrowthRate+i));
   }
```

there is used uninitialized variable `GrowthRate` that results in undefined behavior.

The same problem exist with the uninitialized variable `t1`

```
 double t1;
 //...
 printf("%lf", t1);
```

Comment: Sadly I'm a newbie at C right now, I thought that returning the value of GrowthRate and t1 would provide the value in the main function. I Struggle to find a way to change the code.

Comment: @JamesDean If you want to return a pointer then the function must have the return type double * and the return value should be assigned to a variable.