# If someone could make this code run

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#define Pi 3.14159265358979323846
#define MAX_DATA 120


double Find_GrowthRate(double Data_6hr[MAX_DATA],double Data_24hr[MAX_DATA]);
void Find_DoublingTime(double GrowthRate[MAX_DATA]);


int main()
{
int i;
double t1;
double Data_6hr[MAX_DATA] = {1.77,1.58,1.78,1.82,1.59,1.63,1.74,1.76,1.76,1.56,1.52,1.53,1.75,1.64,1.41,1.72,1.55,1.71,1.74,1.55,
                             0.53,0.51,0.56,0.57,0.53,0.62,0.52,0.60,0.52,0.62,0.52,0.61,0.55,0.59,0.50,0.59,0.58,0.50,0.57,0.61,
                             0.20,0.21,0.21,0.23,0.24,0.21,0.24,0.21,0.20,0.24,0.23,0.23,0.21,0.24,0.23,0.22,0.25,0.21,0.24,0.21,
                             1.46,1.32,1.54,1.25,1.25,1.55,1.23,1.40,1.28,1.52,1.45,1.41,1.21,1.23,1.38,1.43,1.50,1.23,1.21,1.39,
                             0.74,0.88,0.90,0.77,0.82,0.85,0.71,0.90,0.81,0.77,0.81,0.72,0.83,0.87,0.84,0.72,0.71,0.75,0.74,0.75,
                             0.91,0.98,1.03,0.95,0.83,0.89,0.80,1.03,1.03,0.88,0.84,0.95,0.95,0.88,0.89,0.94,0.89,1.03,0.97,1.00};
double Data_24hr[MAX_DATA] ={7.60,7.39,7.57,7.60,7.59,7.25,7.52,7.54,7.61,7.24,7.51,7.28,7.45,7.39,7.27,7.59,7.44,7.59,7.62,7.19,
                             2.67,2.51,2.68,2.65,2.57,2.63,2.65,2.69,2.66,2.72,2.64,2.65,2.58,2.60,2.62,2.64,2.64,2.62,2.61,2.74,
                             1.02,1.06,1.03,1.09,1.06,1.05,1.06,1.06,1.02,1.05,1.09,1.04,1.04,1.08,1.05,1.08,1.10,1.05,1.08,1.07,
                             6.61,6.47,6.45,6.28,6.32,6.38,6.18,6.29,6.23,6.49,6.49,6.47,6.09,6.34,6.20,6.57,6.43,6.04,6.31,6.23,
                             3.70,3.86,3.79,3.60,3.71,3.69,3.68,3.77,3.72,3.59,3.76,3.72,3.81,3.88,3.85,3.56,3.55,3.59,3.59,3.75,
                             4.13,4.26,4.35,4.22,4.12,4.10,4.24,4.25,4.30,4.28,4.05,4.35,4.24,4.23,4.14,4.37,4.18,4.29,4.27,4.25};
 Find_GrowthRate(Data_6hr,Data_24hr);
  double *GrowthRate;
  printf("Growth Rates\n");
for(i=0;i<MAX_DATA;i++){
    printf("%lf \n",*(GrowthRate+i));
}
  Find_DoublingTime(GrowthRate);
  free(GrowthRate);
return 0;
}
double Find_GrowthRate(double Data_6hr[MAX_DATA], double Data_24hr[MAX_DATA])
{
int i;

double *GrowthRate;
GrowthRate = (double*)malloc(MAX_DATA*sizeof(double));
for(i=0;i<MAX_DATA;i++){
   double PopulationSize_t1 = (Pi * pow((Data_6hr[i]/ 2),2));
   printf("%lf\n",PopulationSize_t1);
   double PopulationSize_t2 = (Pi * pow((Data_24hr[i]/ 2),2));
   printf("%lf\n",PopulationSize_t2);
   double x = ((PopulationSize_t2 - PopulationSize_t1) / PopulationSize_t1);
   *(GrowthRate+i) = x;
}
printf("Growth Rates\n");
for(i=0;i<MAX_DATA;i++){
    printf("%lf \n",*(GrowthRate+i));
          }

return *GrowthRate;

}
void Find_DoublingTime(double *GrowthRate)
{
int i;
double x, sum=0, t1, t2, t3, t4, t5, t6;

printf("Growth Rates\n");
for(i=0;i<MAX_DATA;i++){
    printf("%lf \n",*(GrowthRate+i));
}
printf("Average Doubling Population Time : \n");

   for(i=0;i<20;i++){
   x = (log(2)/ log (1+*(GrowthRate+i)));
   sum += x;
}
t1 = sum / 20;
printf("%lf", t1);
sum=0;

   for(i=20;i<40;i++){
   x = (log(2)/ log (1+*(GrowthRate+i)));
   sum += x;
}
t2 = sum / 20;
printf("%lf", t2);
sum=0;

   for(i=40;i<60;i++){
   x = (log(2)/ log (1+GrowthRate[i]));
   sum += x;
}
t3 = sum / 20;
printf("%lf", t3);
sum=0;

   for(i=60;i<80;i++){
   x = (log(2)/ log (1+GrowthRate[i]));
   sum += x;
}
t4 = sum / 20;
printf("%lf", t4);
sum=0;

   for(i=80;i<100;i++){
   x = (log(2)/ log (1+GrowthRate[i]));
   sum += x;
}
t5 = sum / 20;
printf("%lf", t5);
sum=0;

   for(i=100;i<MAX_DATA;i++){
   x = (log(2)/ log (1+GrowthRate[i]));
   sum += x;
}
t6 = sum / 20;
printf("%lf", t6);
}
```

Turns out there are no "errors" in this code and I'm guessing it is to do with my use of pointers.

The point of the code is to provide the average doubling time of a population, the main problem is that I cannot seem to pass the array from my `Find_GrowthRate`function to my `Find_DoublingTime`function.

Any help is appreciated, I'm completely new to C, so examples of changed to the code would be nice.

If someone could actually run this code with valid answers that would be amazing,I believe the data is there.

Comment: I don't know if it's you under a different name but this code has been asked about multiple times in the last day. Exactly the same problem we told the other person - the `Find_GrowthRate` function is declared to return a `double` yet it actually returns `double *`.

Comment: And please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). In particular you need to show/describe the specific error you are getting and ask a specific question - "fix everything for me" is not a specific question.

Comment: Three remarkably similar questions: [Unknown error in my code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40900098/) and 
[Not able to return my array in function to my main function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40899167/) and 
[I don't know how to fix the errors with my code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40897186/).  They are nominally by two different people (other than John dove), but they certainly seem to be addressing the same basic problem.

Answer (score 1):

Two issues here.  First you're returning a `double *` from `Find_GrowthRate` but the function is declared to return a `double`.  Change the return type to `double *`.

```
double *Find_GrowthRate(double Data_6hr[MAX_DATA], double Data_24hr[MAX_DATA])
```

Second, you call `Find_GrowthRate` but don't assign the return value to anything.  On the next line you declare `GrowthRate` and then use it without assigning anything to it.  Assign the return value to `GrowthRate`.

```
  double *GrowthRate = Find_GrowthRate(Data_6hr,Data_24hr);
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your function Find_GrowthRate is returning double while it shoud be returning a double* (the one you are creating by malloc). Also, you need to set the GrowRate variable on main to it (maybe you are thinking it is a global or something?).

Here is the full working thing:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#define Pi 3.14159265358979323846
#define MAX_DATA 120


double* Find_GrowthRate(double Data_6hr[MAX_DATA],double Data_24hr[MAX_DATA]);
void Find_DoublingTime(double GrowthRate[MAX_DATA]);


int main()
{
    int i;
    double t1;
    double Data_6hr[MAX_DATA] = {1.77,1.58,1.78,1.82,1.59,1.63,1.74,1.76,1.76,1.56,1.52,1.53,1.75,1.64,1.41,1.72,1.55,1.71,1.74,1.55,
        0.53,0.51,0.56,0.57,0.53,0.62,0.52,0.60,0.52,0.62,0.52,0.61,0.55,0.59,0.50,0.59,0.58,0.50,0.57,0.61,
        0.20,0.21,0.21,0.23,0.24,0.21,0.24,0.21,0.20,0.24,0.23,0.23,0.21,0.24,0.23,0.22,0.25,0.21,0.24,0.21,
        1.46,1.32,1.54,1.25,1.25,1.55,1.23,1.40,1.28,1.52,1.45,1.41,1.21,1.23,1.38,1.43,1.50,1.23,1.21,1.39,
        0.74,0.88,0.90,0.77,0.82,0.85,0.71,0.90,0.81,0.77,0.81,0.72,0.83,0.87,0.84,0.72,0.71,0.75,0.74,0.75,
        0.91,0.98,1.03,0.95,0.83,0.89,0.80,1.03,1.03,0.88,0.84,0.95,0.95,0.88,0.89,0.94,0.89,1.03,0.97,1.00};
    double Data_24hr[MAX_DATA] ={7.60,7.39,7.57,7.60,7.59,7.25,7.52,7.54,7.61,7.24,7.51,7.28,7.45,7.39,7.27,7.59,7.44,7.59,7.62,7.19,
        2.67,2.51,2.68,2.65,2.57,2.63,2.65,2.69,2.66,2.72,2.64,2.65,2.58,2.60,2.62,2.64,2.64,2.62,2.61,2.74,
        1.02,1.06,1.03,1.09,1.06,1.05,1.06,1.06,1.02,1.05,1.09,1.04,1.04,1.08,1.05,1.08,1.10,1.05,1.08,1.07,
        6.61,6.47,6.45,6.28,6.32,6.38,6.18,6.29,6.23,6.49,6.49,6.47,6.09,6.34,6.20,6.57,6.43,6.04,6.31,6.23,
        3.70,3.86,3.79,3.60,3.71,3.69,3.68,3.77,3.72,3.59,3.76,3.72,3.81,3.88,3.85,3.56,3.55,3.59,3.59,3.75,
        4.13,4.26,4.35,4.22,4.12,4.10,4.24,4.25,4.30,4.28,4.05,4.35,4.24,4.23,4.14,4.37,4.18,4.29,4.27,4.25};

    double *GrowthRate = Find_GrowthRate(Data_6hr,Data_24hr);
    printf("Growth Rates\n");
    for(i=0;i<MAX_DATA;i++){
        printf("%lf \n",*(GrowthRate+i));
    }
    Find_DoublingTime(GrowthRate);
    free(GrowthRate);
    return 0;
}
double *Find_GrowthRate(double Data_6hr[MAX_DATA], double Data_24hr[MAX_DATA])
{
    int i;

    double *GrowthRate;
    GrowthRate = (double*)malloc(MAX_DATA*sizeof(double));
    for(i=0;i<MAX_DATA;i++){
        double PopulationSize_t1 = (Pi * pow((Data_6hr[i]/ 2),2));
        printf("%lf\n",PopulationSize_t1);
        double PopulationSize_t2 = (Pi * pow((Data_24hr[i]/ 2),2));
        printf("%lf\n",PopulationSize_t2);
        double x = ((PopulationSize_t2 - PopulationSize_t1) / PopulationSize_t1);
        *(GrowthRate+i) = x;
    }
    printf("Growth Rates\n");
    for(i=0;i<MAX_DATA;i++){
        printf("%lf \n",*(GrowthRate+i));
    }

    return GrowthRate;

}
void Find_DoublingTime(double *GrowthRate)
{
    int i;
    double x, sum=0, t1, t2, t3, t4, t5, t6;

    printf("Growth Rates\n");
    for(i=0;i<MAX_DATA;i++){
        printf("%lf \n",*(GrowthRate+i));
    }
    printf("Average Doubling Population Time : \n");

    for(i=0;i<20;i++){
        x = (log(2)/ log (1+*(GrowthRate+i)));
        sum += x;
    }
    t1 = sum / 20;
    printf("%lf", t1);
    sum=0;

    for(i=20;i<40;i++){
        x = (log(2)/ log (1+*(GrowthRate+i)));
        sum += x;
    }
    t2 = sum / 20;
    printf("%lf", t2);
    sum=0;

    for(i=40;i<60;i++){
        x = (log(2)/ log (1+GrowthRate[i]));
        sum += x;
    }
    t3 = sum / 20;
    printf("%lf", t3);
    sum=0;

    for(i=60;i<80;i++){
        x = (log(2)/ log (1+GrowthRate[i]));
        sum += x;
    }
    t4 = sum / 20;
    printf("%lf", t4);
    sum=0;

    for(i=80;i<100;i++){
        x = (log(2)/ log (1+GrowthRate[i]));
        sum += x;
    }
    t5 = sum / 20;
    printf("%lf", t5);
    sum=0;

    for(i=100;i<MAX_DATA;i++){
        x = (log(2)/ log (1+GrowthRate[i]));
        sum += x;
    }
    t6 = sum / 20;
    printf("%lf", t6);
}
```

Comment: Wow, you are literally the only person who has managed to help me, words cant describe how relieved I am.Thank you.